# Axiom Deathmatch: Final Classes

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, orm

Hibernate Community Documentation :

> "A central feature of Hibernate, proxies (lazy loading), depends upon
>   the persistent class being either non-final, or the implementation of
>   an interface that declares all public methods. You can persist final
>   classes that do not implement an interface with Hibernate; you will
>   not, however, be able to use proxies for lazy association fetching
>   which will ultimately limit your options for performance tuning."

Effective Java Second Edition :

> "Design & document for inheritance or else prohibit it"

Well, which one is right, or better yet, while using hibernate when should I follow one principle or the other? Should I make all classes final until I need the extra performance of using dynamic proxies? If I choose to use final classes, can I implement interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no hard laws, only guidelines. Effective Java is a great set of java axioms  that should further investigated , validated, and meditated on. When it comes to our livelihood, however, we typically have little say on the hand we are given. never blindly follow *any* philosophy. Put in the work, do the tests and choose the right "Way" for the job.